# Laravel Update Blade Language with Javascript Cookie

Tags: php, laravel

Currently working on a project where the language needs to be allowed to toggle and the change needs to be remembered, I currently have a cookie made with vue-cookies which is set and checked in my header.vue file, it alters the locale of the i18n.js file to the value on the cookie. The issue I'm having now is I can't get this cookie to update the language on any blade.php files, such as the register.blade.php file.

Currently I have a header.blade.php file that updates the language through a route and controller, which alters the config locale which updates any strings within `{{ __(x.y) }}`.

Is there no way to access the data that I've stored in this cookie in blade.php files? If there are, can I get a link on how to do this if it doesn't include vue-cookies and if it can still work in .vue files.

My header.vue file contains the following inside script tags and is set as a method inside export default:

```
            switchLangauge(locale) {
                if(this.$cookies.isKey('language')){
                  this.$cookies.set('language', locale);
                  console.log('language: ' + this.$cookies.get('language'));
                  i18n.locale = locale;
                  this.lang = locale;
                }
                else{
                  this.$cookies.set('language', locale);
                  console.log('cannot find cookie language');
                }
            }
```

I've recently tried to use the standard PHP cookie reference `$_COOKIE['language']` which is now able to update the register.blade.php file to indicate what language is selected however, I'm still experiencing the issue of not being able to transfer language selection between vue and blade files.

Inside of blade I'm using a URL to change the config locale which I have modified to attempt to update the cookie I created in js.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        config(['app.locale' => $id]);
        $response = new Illuminate\Http\Response('language');
        $response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('langauge', $id));
        return $response;
    }
```

The route is a put and the id should be en/cy but every time I try to run this it fails to update.

Web.php route file:

```
Route::get('locale/{locale}', function($locale){
    Session::put('locale', $locale);
    return redirect()->back();
});
```

How can I modify the methods to allow the language to be changed between the two types of views?

Comment: `{{ __(x.y) }}`

Comment: Am I going about this in the wrong way? or is there something I need to do when creating the cookie?